# Python. Не работает вложенный цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте! Только учусь. Помогите с задачей реализовать программку именно через использование словарей и циклов. Первый цикл проходит все ключи, а вложенный только первое значение и дальше не идет, выдает ошибочный ответ при сравнивании пользовательского ввода и значения

```
questions = {'Какой язык мы изучаем?': 'Python',
             'Что означает пустота в Python?': 'None',
             'Назовите обозначение вещественного типа?': 'Float'}

correct_answer = 0
incorrect_answer = 0

for question in questions.keys():
    print(question)

    for answer in questions.values():
        user_input = str(input('Введите ответ: ').lower())

        if user_input in answer.lower():
            correct_answer += 1
            break
        else:
            incorrect_answer += 1
            break

print('Правильных ответов: {}'.format(correct_answer))
print('Неправильных ответов: {}'.format(incorrect_answer))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странный подход для решения такой задачи, попробуйте так:

```
In [6]: questions = {'Какой язык мы изучаем?': 'Python',
   ...:              'Что означает пустота в Python?': 'None',
   ...:              'Назовите обозначение вещественного типа?': 'Float'}
   ...:

In [7]: correct_answers = 0

In [8]: for quest, answer in questions.items():
   ...:     print(quest)
   ...:     if input('Answer?: ') == answer:
   ...:         correct_answers += 1
   ...: print('correct answers: {}'.format(correct_answers))
   ...: print('wrong answers: {}'.format(len(questions) - correct_answers))
```

Answer (score 1):

В твоем коде break прерывает цикл и он останавливается, просто убери break в if и else и все заработает.